# ConfuserEx.exe in pre/ post build executing asynchronous in VS

Tags: visual-studio, obfuscation, pre-build-event, confuserex

I have an installer project that is generating `.msi` on build. In the pre-build event, I am calling `Confuser.CLI.exe` to obfuscate code, but `exe` is working asynchronous and taking too much time, and the compiler is finished before `exe`, so I have `.msi` with old `DLLs` and then when `.msi` is generated, new `DLLs` overwrite old ones. I even tried with the post-build event, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside installer project - `.wixproj`, I put 2 targets that will execute different commands:

```
  <Target Name="ConfuserExScript" AfterTargets="CopyReferencedProjects">
    <Exec Command="Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File &quot;$(SolutionDir)Installers\Scripts\Build\PostBuild_RunConfuserEx.ps1&quot; &quot;$(SolutionDir)\&quot;" />
  </Target>

  <Target Condition=" '$(ConfigurationName)' == 'ReleaseDC' " Name="Obfuscator" AfterTargets="ConfuserExScript">
    <Exec Command="$(SolutionDir)Installers\ConfuserEx\Confuser.CLI.exe $(ProjectDir)ConfuserOutput.crproj" />
  </Target>
```

The first one is gathering DLLs and creating `crproj` file for `ConfuserEx`, the second one is running `Confuser.CLI.exe` and obfuscating code.
Important thing is that I use `afterTargets` so the second line is executed after the first one is finished.